# ограничение в xcode? установил программу, перестала работать

Tags: ios, xcode, app

Добрый день всем!

У меня вот такая проблема:

я установил на телефон (iphone) программу из xcode для тестов (свою) через какое то время она перестала работать и это не первый раз.

По ковырявшись в интернете я понял, что там какой то лимит типа, если хочешь пользоваться программой то заплати за аккаунт разработчика и пользуйся

так ли это и можно ли обойти это все дело.

Comment: что то вы путаете. платный аккаунт нужен только чтоб загружать в аппстор

Comment: ссылку потерял, прочитал на форуме, что установленные приложения через xcode имеют определенное время потом какой то сертификат истекает и все, у меня приложение, не запускается после определенного времени, что в 9 было то и в 10 xcode 7.3.1 и 8 все одно и то же. если вы знаете можете написать, а не по делу не нужно

Comment: любой сертификат работает год и потом истекает. не думаю, что это то, с чем вы столкнулись

Comment: ааа как то можно обойти это ограничение, чтоб например если я в деревне и у меня нет интернета, запустить программу на устройстве и она работала сколько мне нужно или это  только через jailbreak.